# CQL: How does cassandra discriminator_column works

Tags: python, cassandra, cql, cqlengine

I'm asking about cassandra [model-inheritance](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/python/2.5/cqlengine/models.html#model-inheritance).

Does anyone know how it works in CQL?

Does it cassandra feature or python-driver implementation?

What is the best way to store multiple similar models in one row?

Comment: I try understand sources of python-driver, but no results right now...

Comment: it creates all columns from childs in base model, then ignore it.

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.19/cqlengine/models/#model-inheritance It's nicely explained here.